# QML Dialog Not Resizing To Accommodate Content

Tags: qt, qml

**Overview**

I'm designing a `Dialog` in QML. The header property uses a `TabBar` to allow the user to select different pages in the dialog which are held in the contentItem property using `StackLayout`. However when I open the dialog, its default visual components are sized to the smallest possible dimensions and the items in contentItem spill out the sides:

[image: Dialog with components spilling out the sides]

(Also of note is how low-contrast the default text is, but one issue at a time.)

The behavior I'd like to see is that the dialog loads with its dimensions set to the maximum of its child elements. That is, if the `StackLayout` contains two items, one wider than the other, I would like `Dialog`'s width to accommodate the wider item, even if the less wide item is currently being displayed.

**Code**

Here's a minimal example showing this behavior:

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Dialog {
        id: myDialog

        title: "Example Dialog"

        modal: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape

        standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel

        header: TabBar {
            id: bar

            TabButton {text: "Tab1"}
            TabButton {text: "Tab2"}
        }

        contentItem: StackLayout {
            currentIndex: bar.currentIndex

            Item {
                Rectangle {
                    color: "blue"
                    width: 100
                    height: 200
                }
            }

            Item {
                Rectangle {
                    color: "red"
                    width: 200
                    height: 100
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        text: "Open Dialog"
        onPressed: myDialog.open()
    }
}
```

**What I've Tried**

I've looked through the documentation for [Dialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-dialog.html#details) but didn't see any mention of how to manage its size. I also tried directly setting the `Dialog`'s height to `implicitContentHeight + implicitHeaderHeight` and width to `implicitContentWidth`, but that caused the Dialog's visual components to disappear upon opening it. I don't think that the `Dialog` type's dimensions are supposed to be directly set, that it should be allowed to automatically resize.

Comment: The Fusion text colour issue is tracked here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-99276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that StackLayout doesn't know the implicit (or preferred) size of its items.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Dialog {
        id: myDialog
        title: "Example Dialog"
        modal: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape
        standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel
        visible: true

        header: TabBar {
            id: bar

            TabButton {text: "Tab1"}
            TabButton {text: "Tab2"}
        }

        contentItem: StackLayout {
            currentIndex: bar.currentIndex

            Item {
                implicitWidth: blueRect.implicitWidth
                implicitHeight: blueRect.implicitHeight

                Rectangle {
                    id: blueRect
                    color: "blue"
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 200
                }
            }

            Item {
                implicitWidth: redRect.implicitWidth
                implicitHeight: redRect.implicitHeight

                Rectangle {
                    id: redRect
                    color: "red"
                    implicitWidth: 200
                    implicitHeight: 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do:

```
            Item {
                Layout.preferredWidth: blueRect.implicitWidth
                Layout.preferredHeight: blueRect.implicitHeight

                // ...
```

Layouts and controls use implicit size to know what the implicit/default/natural size of the item should be.

Comment: Trying the first suggestion yielded the same results as my previous attempts, but setting `Layout.preferredHeight` and `Layout.preferredWidth` did the trick!